# MSDN contradicts Visual-Studio (MediaPlayerState vs MediaPlaybackState)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app, msdn

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackstate.aspx) says about MediaPlaybackState:

> MediaPlaybackState may be altered or unavailable after Windows 10,
>   version 1607. Use MediaPlayerState instead.

But Visual Studio warns me that:

> 'MediaPlayerState' is obsolete: 'Use MediaPlaybackState instead of
>   MediaPlayerState.  For more info, see MSDN.'

So which one should be used?

Comment: based on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayerstate.aspx 'MediaPlayerState' has attribute [Deprecated()] so technically its MSDN contradicting itself. Should probably open up a connect ticket

Comment: Thanks for the report, I have sent it on internally. Hopefully will be fixed in the future.

Comment: I've got the same problem. So should I use MediaPlaybackState instead of MediaPlayerState? And should I use MediaPlayerElement (xaml) instead MediaElement (xaml)? Looks like that the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing at Microsoft anymore.